# Vim python3 integration on mac

Tags: macos, python-3.x, vim

I'm trying to work out to integrate Python3 into Vim, I know I need to do it when compiling vim but I cant seem to get it right. I'm using **homebrew** to install with the following script:

`brew install vim --override-system-vim --with-python3`

It installs vim however when i check the version, python3 is still not supported.

Comment: So you want to compile vim? Or install with homebrew?

Comment: I want to install with homebrew, but having python3 set as default and not python 2

Comment: @Miles Did you manage to correct this? I thought I had the same issue but realised I needed to re-start the shell. If the problem still persists, it may be that you have older versions that homebrew is still trying to install. `brew cleanup` would remove older _bottles_ and perhaps allow you to install the latest. If this is still giving you trouble, I found removing vim (`brew uninstall --force vim`) and then reinstalling (`brew install vim --override-system-vim --with-python3`) worked for me.

Comment: That works @tiko - you may want to post an answer for others.

Comment: Thanks @Mick, just posted an answer, if you could upvote it that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution - $ brew install vim --with-python3

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had the same issue but realised I needed to re-start the shell.

If the problem still persists, it may be that you have older versions that homebrew is still trying to install. `brew cleanup` would remove older *bottles* and perhaps allow you to install the latest.

If this is still giving you trouble, I found removing vim with `brew uninstall --force vim` and then reinstalling with `brew install vim --override-system-vim --with-python3` worked for me.

**EDIT** 2018-08-22

Python 3 is now default when compiling vim. Therefore the command below should integrate vim with Python 3 automatically.

`brew install vim --override-system-vim`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with the latest OS for mac at this date.

Hope it works for you.

brew install vim python3